# How to limit login to 3 attempts?

Tags: python

Code :

```
counter = 1

pg3_txtbox_username = Entry(page3, borderwidth=0, width=16, font=('Arial',30))
pg3_txtbox_username.place(x=116, y=256, height=92)
pg3_txtbox_pass = Entry(page3, borderwidth=0, width=16, font=('Arial', 30), show='*')
pg3_txtbox_pass.place(x=116, y=422, height=90)

    def verify():
        conn = sqlite3.connect("data/data.db")
        cursor = conn.cursor()

        global counter
        counter = 1
        uname = pg3_txtbox_username.get()
        pwd = pg3_txtbox_pass.get()
        adm = "Admin"
        state = "On"
        
        if uname=='' or pwd=='':
            messagebox.showinfo("Error", "Please Fill The Empty Field!!")
        elif counter <=3:
            cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM faculty_data WHERE Username = '" + str(uname) + "' AND  Password = '" + str(pwd) + "' AND  Position = '" + str(adm) + "' AND Status ='" + str(state) + "'")
            if cursor.fetchone():
                show_frame(page4)
                messagebox.showinfo("Messgae", "WELCOME USER")

                pg3_txtbox_username.delete(0, END)
                pg3_txtbox_pass.delete(0, END)
                check_button.deselect()

            else:
                counter += 1
                messagebox.showinfo("Error", "Reamaining Attempt: "+ str(counter))
                pg3_txtbox_username.delete(0, END)
                pg3_txtbox_pass.delete(0, END)
                check_button.deselect()
```

Result :

[image]

This is always the result. It doesn't increase counter. If I try a while loop it continues to loop. If I remove the counter under the global counter it also has an error.

```
global counter
counter = 1
```

Error :

```
"C:\Users\kenjo\OneDrive\Documents\PythonProject\face_recognition\face_recog.py", line 516, in verify
 elif counter <=3: 
NameError: name 'counter' is not defined
```

Comment: What sense does it make to have a login if the user can read the database file with the clear text credentials?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You have

```py
        global counter
        counter = 1
```

which is setting `counter` to `1` every time `verify()` is called. `verify()` is called every time you check the password, I assume. Therefore, `counter` will be set to `1` every time you verify a password -- and since you add one when you find that the password is incorrect... you end with the behavior shown.

Therefore, you should just delete the `counter = 1` line that is right below the `global` declaration.

Comment: if i delete the counter = 1 under the global declaration the result is error

File "C:\Users\kenjo\OneDrive\Documents\PythonProject\face_recognition\face_recog.py", line 516, in verify
    elif counter <=3:
NameError: name 'counter' is not defined